# From eigenvectors to eigentensors. Is eigentensor (hypermatrix) theory developed and useful?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Just as eigenvectors are invariant vectors up to a multiplicative constant $Au=\lambda u$, I wondered if eigentensor theory is equally developed for any arbitray tensor or hypermatrix array, i.e., $AB=\lambda B$, where A and B are suitable hyperobjects, and, maybe, even $\lambda$ could be an eigentensor as well.

Related: Why should we encounter eigentensors naturally? Is the eigentensor/hypermatrix theory hard? Any nice reference for current status of the subject including something else beyond hyperdeterminants (Kapranov et alii)?

Comment: You might be interested in the theory of eigenoperators.

Comment: That thing...Does really exist? LoL Academia is obsolete, really! ;) Any reference?

Comment: It could also be called an eigenvector, just in a "vector space" of tensors.  For example, on the space of $n \times n$ real matrices ${\text M}_n(\mathbf R)$ the transpose operation $B \mapsto B^\top$ is a linear operator of order 2 and the symmetric matrices are all eigenvectors of this operator.  The function $e^{\lambda x}$ is an eigenvector of the differentiation operator $d/dx$, with eigenvalue $\lambda$, although in the setting of analysis these are called eigenfunctions instead of eigenvectors, but *it's the same thing*.

Comment: @riemannium I've only seen it scattered across papers, but not in books. I'd suggest searching around and finding papers that seem relevant.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to both questions is yes. The theory is very new, but here are two textbooks you could explore:

- Liqun Qi & Ziyan Luo - [Tensor Analysis: Spectral Theory and Special Tensors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1611974747) (2017) -- A modern introduction to hypermatrices. It includes an entire chapter on eigenvalues.
- Liqun Qi & Haibin Chen & Yannan Chen - [Tensor Eigenvalues and Their Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9811080577) (2018) -- This book will answer the question of why they are useful. It includes applications to diffusion tensor imaging, mechanics, and quantum physics.

Comment: Thanks so much.